# UITableView CoreData Assertion Failure

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data, tableview

I am getting this error in my console when my iPhone app crashes:

`*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2372/UITableView.m:1070`

It crashes and give me this when reaching this line of code:

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

A little detail about my app and how I came to this. I have a view controller with a table view which displays my core data objects. I have this view setup to display data from two entities, so table section 1 shows objects from on entity, then section 2 shows objects from my second entity.

This is where my issue begins. While this has worked out fairly well, I can push my next view controller, and add objects to my first entity and pop right back to my tableviewcontroller without an issue. However, if I try and add an object to the second entity, upon returning to my tableviewcontroller it crashes as I described above.

I can't work out what's causing this and so I'm unsure where to start looking.

Some extra error info from the console:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSInteger rows;

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfoAccounts = [[fetchedResultsControllerAccounts sections] objectAtIndex:0];
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfoCosts = [[fetchedResultsControllerCosts sections] objectAtIndex:0];

    if (section == 0) rows = [sectionInfoAccounts numberOfObjects];
    else if (section == 1) rows = [sectionInfoCosts numberOfObjects];

    return rows;
}
```

Comment: Xcode should have printed more about the assertion failure.  Edit your post to include everything it printed.

Comment: That is literally all I get in the console.

Comment: Managed to get more error info. Check my question.

Comment: Note, the error says 'invalid number of rows in section 0'. However, I only get this crash when I am trying to insert a row into section 1. Another little confusion I don't get, it is getting the wrong index somewhere?

Comment: Even if you only modified section 1, the table view is still allowed to ask about section 0.  Your data source and delegate must be ready to return correct information about any section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using 2 fetched results controllers for the table view: one FRC for table section 0 and one FRC for table section 1. I am a little bit guessing here, but it could be that the error is in

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

If the function is called for the second FRC, the section part of `indexPath`/`newIndexPath` is 0 (because the FRC has only one section). But the corresponding table section is 1.

Therefore you must map the FRC index path to the table views's index path before calling `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:...`, `insertRowsAtIndexPaths:...` etc.

For example in the case of a insert event:

```
NSIndexPath *newIndexPath1 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:1];
[self.tableView insertItemsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath1]];
```

Otherwise new objects of the second entity are inserted as rows for the first table view section, which leads to the inconsistency exception.

Comment: This actually makes a lot of sense, thanks. I have added `if (controller == fetchedResultsControllerCosts) newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newIndexPath.row inSection:1];` to the mentioned method and it stops the error I am seeing. However, now this results in an array object out of bounds error when reaching `Cost *cost = [fetchedResultsControllerCosts objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];` when configuring the cell.

Comment: Turns out I just needed to change the section there as well, to 0 this time. As the objects are in section 0 of the FRC but 1 of the table.